# Real time object detection (sift)?

Tags: java, c++, image-processing, opencv

I am investigatin this field to obtain object detection in real time.

Video example:

- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bm5qUG-06V8
- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aYd2kAN0Y20

But how can they extract sift keypoint and matching them so fast?
SIFT extraction requires a second generally

Comment: I think you can find answers here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6960455/sift-and-keypoint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SIFT can be accelerated in several ways :

- if you can afford approximations, then you can derive a keypoint called SURF which is way faster (using integral images for most tasks)
- you can use parallel implementations, at the CPU level (e.g. OpenCV uses Intel's TBB) or at the GPU level (google for sift gpu for related code and doc).

Anyway, none of these is available (AFAIK) in Java, so you'll have to use a Java wrapper to opencv or work it out yourself.

Answer (score 4):

I'm an OpenIMAJ developer and responsible for making the first video.

We're not doing anything particularly fancy to make the matching fast in that video, and the SIFT detection and extraction is carried out on the entirety of every frame. In fact that video was made well before we did any optimisation; the current version of that demo is much smoother. We do also have a version with a hybrid KLT-tracker that works even faster by not having to perform SIFT on every frame.

As suggested by @Mario, the image size does have a big effect on the speed of the extraction, so processing a smaller frame can give a big win. Secondly, in the original description of the difference of Gaussian interest point localisation suggested by Lowe in the SIFT paper, it was suggested that the input image was first doubled in size to increase the number of features. By not performing this double-sizing you also get a big performance boost at the expense of having fewer features to match.

The code is open source (BSD license) and you can get it by following the links at http://www.openimaj.org. As stated in the video description, the image-processing code is pure Java; the only native code is a thin interface to the webcam. Tutorial number 7 in the [current tutorial pdf document](http://openimaj.org/tutorial.pdf) walks through the process of using SIFT in OpenIMAJ. Disabling the double-sizing can be achieved by doing:

```
DoGSIFTEngine engine = new DoGSIFTEngine();
engine.getOptions().setDoubleInitialImage(false);
```

Answer (score 2):

General and first idea: Ask the video uploader(s). We can just assume what's done or how it's done. It might also help to know what you've done so far (e.g. your video resolution, your processing power, image preparation, etc.).

I haven't used SIFT specifically, but I did quite some object/motion tracking during the last few years, so this is more in general. You might have tried some points already, I don't know.

- Reduce your image resolution: Going from 640x480 to 320x240 will reduce your data to 25%. Going down to 160x120 will cut it by another 25% (so 6.25 % data left) without significantly impacting your algorithm.
- In a similar way, it might be useful to reduce the color depth of your image (not just 256 grayscale, but maybe even more; like 64 colors).
- Try other methods to make features more obvious or faster to find, e.g. try running an edge detector over your image.
- At least the second video mentions a tracking system, so you could try to guess the region where the object tracked should reappear the next frame (using some simple a/b filter or whatever on coordinates and possibly rotation), then use SIFT on that sub area (with some added margin) only. Only analyze the whole image if you can't find it again. At around 40 or 50 seconds in the second video they're losing the object and need quite some time/tries to find it again.

Comment: Yea I assume they extract sift only on a small portion of images, and if tehy don't find it they will search in the whole image slowing it down. But still it's pretty damn fast